# How to display item description and shipping address during paypal PHP parallel payment?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have to implement a merchant website where a customers pays a seller for some material goods and a service fee to the website via paypal as described on the picture.

I know that I need to use adaptive payments (parallel or chained) and that the REST API does not support these payments yet (correct me if I'm wrong).

The problem with the classic API (NVP/SOAP) is that during the payment when the webpage redirects the customer to paypal, paypal does not show any item name or description. The other problem is that when the customer logs in no shipping information is shown and no shipping address is sent to the seller after the purchase is made.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

[image: Desired result]

**Note:** The photo shows the desired result which is not achieved in my website.

**Note 2:** I want to use the shipping address that the user used when he/she set up the paypal account and not send it again when I make API calls from PHP

Thank you!

P.S. Some websites that do this kind of payment, on their redirect url to paypal have `https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/merchantpaymentweb?cmd=_flow&SESSION=.....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do **Parallel Payment** without the Adaptive Payments API.
The **Express Checkout API** give you the option to add multiple receivers.

If you use the NVP string in your API call, you can do the following to have 2 receivers:

```
$nvpreq="METHOD=" . $METHOD //required
. "&VERSION=" . $VERSION  //required
. "&PWD=" . $PWD  //required
. "&USER=" . $USER  //required
. "&SIGNATURE=" . $SIGNATURE  //required
. "&RETURNURL=" . $RETURNURL  //required
. "&CANCELURL=" . $CANCELURL  //required    

. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC=" . $OVERALLDESCRIPTION  //optional but best practices
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $PAYMENTACTION //optional but best practices
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=" . $TOTALAMT //required = PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT + PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT + PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT + PAYMENTREQUEST_0_INURANCEAMT
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=" . $TOTALITEMAMT  //optional but best practice = (L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0 x L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0) + (L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1 x L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1)
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=" . $SHIPPINGAMOUNT  //optional but best practices
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=" . $CURRENCYCODE  //optional but best practices
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=" . $TAX  //optional but best practices

//1st seller information, specific to parallel payment
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=" . $SELLER1
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTREQUESTID=" . $UNIQUESELLERID1

. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NOTIFYURL=" . $IPNURL  //optional but best practices

//Line items - (optional)
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=" . $DESCRIPTION1 //optional but best practices
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=" . $DESCRIPTION1 //optional but best practices
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=" . $PAYMENTREQUEST_AMT1 //optional but best practices
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=" . $PAYMENTQUANTITY1 //optional but best practices

. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME1=" . $DESCRIPTION2 //optional but best practices
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC1=" . $DESCRIPTION2 //optional but best practices
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT1=" . $PAYMENTREQUEST_AMT2 //optional but best practices
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY1=" . $PAYMENTQUANTITY2 //optional but best practices

. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME2=" . $DISCOUNTTXT //optional but best practices
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC2=" . $DISCOUNTTXT //optional but best practices
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT2=" . $DISCOUNTAMT //optional but best practices
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY2=" . $DISCOUNTQTY //optional but best practices

//Address information
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTONAME=" . $SHIPPINGNAME
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET=" . $SHIPPINGSTREET
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTREET2=" . $SHIPPINGSTREET2
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCITY=" . $SHIPPINGCITY
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOSTATE=" . $SHIPPINGSTATE
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOZIP=" . $SHIPPINGZIPCODE
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOCOUNTRYCODE=" . $SHIPPINGCOUNTRYCODE
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPTOPHONENUM=" . $SHIPTOPHONENUM

//2nd seller information
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_DESC=" . $DESCRIPTIONSELLER2
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTACTION=" . $PAYMENTACTIONSELLER2
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT=" . $AMOUNTSELLER2
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMAMT=" . $AMOUNTSELLER2
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_CURRENCYCODE=" . $CURRENCYCODESELLER2
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_SELLERPAYPALACCOUNTID=" . $SELLER2
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_1_PAYMENTREQUESTID=" . $UNIQUESELLERID2

. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NAME0=" . $DESCRIPTIONSELLER2
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_DESC0=" . $DESCRIPTIONSELLER2
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT0=" . $AMOUNTSELLER2
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_QTY0=" . $QUANTITYSELLER2
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital"


//Payment page settings
. "&ALLOWNOTE=" . $ALLOWNOTE
. "&ADDROVERRIDE=" . $ADDROVERRIDE
. "&NOSHIPPING=" . $NOSHIPPING
. "&LOCALECODE=" . $LOCALECODE
. "&LANDINGPAGE=" . $LANDINGPAGE;
```

As you can see, we have two receivers, but you can add more. For each receiver you can add line items which will appear on the payment page.

In this example I add the line items only for the first receiver. If you want to add the line items for the 2nd receiver, simply add the following to the NVP string:

```
. "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_NAME0=" . $DESCRIPTION1 //optional but best practices
    . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_DESC0=" . $DESCRIPTION1 //optional but best practices
    . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_AMT0=" . $PAYMENTREQUEST_AMT1 //optional but best practices
    . "&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_1_QTY0=" . $PAYMENTQUANTITY1 //optional but best practices
```

Once the user return back to your website (return url), call the GetExpressCheckout API and store the result in a variable:

```
$nvpreq="USER=" . $_SESSION['USER'] 
. "&PWD=" . $_SESSION['PWD'] 
. "&SIGNATURE=" . $_SESSION['SIGNATURE']
. "&METHOD=GetExpressCheckoutDetails"
. "&VERSION=" . $_SESSION['VERSION']      
. "&TOKEN=" . $_SESSION['PP_TOKEN']
;
//Send the NVP string to the PayPal server, store the result in a variable.
$resultECD = ....
```

Eventually build the NVP string with the GetExpressCheckout result and call the DoExpressCheckoutPayment:

```
$nvpDoECReq="USER=" . $_SESSION['USER'] 
. "&PWD=" . $_SESSION['PWD'] 
. "&SIGNATURE=" . $_SESSION['SIGNATURE']
. "&METHOD=DoExpressCheckoutPayment"      
. "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=" . $_SESSION['PAYMENT_ACTION'];     // payment type

//Build the DoExpressCheckout request
foreach ($resultECD as $i => $value) {  
//Ignore some elements of the GetExpressCheckoutDetails answer
    if ((!($i == "CHECKOUTSTATUS")) && (!($i == "TIMESTAMP")) && (!($i == "CORRELATIONID")) && (!($i == "ACK")) && (!($i == "BUILD"))) {
                    $nvpDoECReq = $nvpDoECReq . "&" . urldecode($i) . "=" . urldecode($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I didn't know I could do parallel payments with express checkout, you saved my life. Although, when I call DoExpressCheckoutPayment only the 'service' payment is done, for the other main payment it says that it is A duplicate payment (A successful transaction has already been completed for this token.) and has an Internal Error. Is this because I am making two payments (parallel)? Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I can help. The DoExpressCheckoutPayment should work. What nvp string are you passing? In my code I'm passing the same variables as the one built in the SetExpressCheckout, with the line items and everything. Are you calling GetExpressCheckoutDetails as well?

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Yes after the returnUrl I call the GetExpressCheckoutDetails and DoExpressCheckoutPayment with the same nvp string but I add the token and PayerId which are returned from paypal. In both cases I get a SuccessWithWarning with [L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Duplicate Request; The first payment which must go to the seller has failed due to Internal Error and the second payment which is for the service is successful. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please have a look at my updated post. I add the other API call. It should help you.

Comment: Thank you, it was a nice way to generate the string and I found the problem but I am unable to find a solution. The GetExpressCheckoutDetails doesn't return TransactionId for both the payments (only for the second one) and it is probably because the payment to the first receiver failed. If I can have any help about this problem I would be grateful. Thank you.